# Quick Enum Question

Tags: java, enums

Hey guys,  I have a quick question.  If given a string Value how can i get the corresponding int value in my enum class?

Ex:

Given a string "Ordinary"  I want the value 0 returned.  Here is what I have:

```
public enum MembershipTypes 
{
    ORDINARY(0,"Ordinary"),
    WORKING(1,"Working"),
    CORE(2,"Core"),
    COORDINATOR(3,"Coordinator");

    private int intVal;
    private String strVal;

    /**
     * 
     * @param intValIn
     * @param strValIn
     */
    MembershipTypes(int intValIn, String strValIn)
    {
        intVal = intValIn;
        strVal = strValIn;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Gets the integer value
     * @return intVal
     */
    public int getIntVal() 
    {
        return intVal;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Gets the string value
     * @return strVal
     */
    public String getStrVal() 
    {
        return strVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need separate non monotonic intVals? Otherwise you could drop that member and getter and constructor value and just use the enum ordinal. FurtherMore if you are willing to have the string be the enum, you'd be done...

Comment: "Quick enum question" is not a good question title.

Comment: In what purpose are you using this enum class? I might not have the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest way to do it. Add this static method to your enum:

```
public static int getIntValForString(String strVal) {
   for (MembershipTypes e : MembershipTypes.values()) {
      if (e.getStrVal().equals(strVal)) {
         return e.getIntVal();
      }
   }
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such enum for string val:" + strVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
private static final Map<String, MEMBERSHIP_TYPES> MEMBERSHIP_TYPES = new HashMap<String, MembershipTypes>;
static {
  for (MembershipTypes membershipType : values()){
     MEMBERSHIP_TYPES.put(membershipType.strVal, membershipType);
  }
}

public static int getIntVal(String strVal){
  if (! MEMBERSHIP_TYPES.containsKey(strVal){
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value: " + strVal);
  }
  return MEMBERSHIP_TYPES.get(strVal).getIntVal();
}
```

Consider:

- renaming MembershipTypes to MembershipType
- renaming intVal and strVal to more meaningful property names if possible

Answer (score 0):

Your enum automatically gets a method `valueOf(String)` that returns the right enum when given an enum name. You can override that to also check for your `strVal`. Alternatively, you could write a utility function that returns the int value directly.

Comment: That won't work for his example, because each enum instance contains a separate string value (apart from the instance name), and that's the value he wants to use for lookup.

Comment: @benjismith - true enough; I read through the post too quickly. I'm amending my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ordinal().